# Find and remove duplicated keys in a document

Tags: mongodb

Because of an accident while coding that our documents are having some duplicated keys. For an example of a document

```
{
   key1: {}
   key1: null
}
```

Is there an easy way to find keys like that and remove the first one or the one which having value that is null across documents in a collection?

Thanks

Comment: do you have duplicate key in one doc ?

Comment: Yes, a lot of documents, so I need a way to detect and keep only one

Comment: I coudlnt simulate your scenario and add doc with duplicate key

Comment: You can see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names